# Express.js and connect-mongo session "TypeError: Cannot read property 'upserted' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session, express

I am trying to store sessions using [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) module, however I get the following Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'upserted' of undefined
```

The usage of `connect-mongo` looks as follows:

```
import session from 'express-session';
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
  secret: 'SECRET',
  store: new MongoStore({ url: 'mongodb://mongo:27017/sessions' }),
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false
}));
```

At the same time, I can see that session entries are being created on every page reload with the following contents:

```
{
  "_id": "zO68C8OuARTUblw3EqHfUikR_IIHRaQq",
  "session": "{\"cookie\": \"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"    }}",
  "expires": new Date(1470779765287)
}
```

And the expiration date is set to 14 days from the creation timestamp (default value)

Package versions used:

```
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"connect-mongo": "^1.3.1",
"express": "~4.0.0",
"express-session": "^1.14.0",
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you're trying to access the property `upserted` of an `undefined` object. Nowhere in the code that you're providing does the use of `upserted` get shown, can you provide any code that shows `upserted` being used?

Comment: the error is referencing this piece of the connect-mongo code, located at line 249 of node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js: `return this.collectionReady()
                .then(collection => collection.updateAsync({ _id: this.computeStorageId(sid) }, s, { upsert: true }))
                .then(rawResponse => {
                    if (rawResponse.result.upserted) {
                        this.emit('create', sid);
                    } else {
                        [...]`

Comment: I tried reusing the mongoose connection, `server.app.use(session({
  secret: 'SECRETO',
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connections[0] }),
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false
}));` and while the `upserted` error disappears, I see that not a single new session has been created in mongo

Answer (score 1):

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/230) on connect-mongo repository, and indeed, the issue has already been resolved in the latest version 1.3.2 :)